# SQL Server Database restore does not match the database backed up

Tags: sql-server, database, continuous-integration

I have a nightly build and deployment for an application that uses a SQL server database. The process involves dropping the previously created database and re-creating it with the new SQL from the build. As part of this build and deployment, the newly created database gets backed up and restored to have junits run on it. However the restored database for the junits does not match the database that gets backed up. A summary of the process is below:

```
drop product_db
drop junit_db

create product_db
delete backup of product_db
create backup of product_db
restore product_db into junit_db
```

But after this, the databases do not match. It seems to be restoring the first ever backup of the product_db. Even though the previous backup gets deleted.

The command used to backup the database is:

```
SQLCMD -Usa -P$adminPwd -S$dbServer -m-1 -b -Q "BACKUP DATABASE [${secDb}] TO DISK = '${winMssqlPath}\\${secDb}_tmp.bak'";
```

Restore command:

```
SQLCMD -Usa -P$adminPwd -S$dbServer -m-1 -b -Q "RESTORE DATABASE [${newSecDb}] FROM  DISK = N'${winMssqlPath}\\${secDb}_tmp.bak' WITH  FILE = 1, REPLACE, MOVE N'${secDb}' TO N'${MSSQLDATA_HOME}\\DATA\\${newSecDb}.mdf',  MOVE N'${secDb}_log' TO N'${MSSQLDATA_HOME}\\DATA\\${newSecDb}_1.LDF',  NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10";
```

Does anyone have idea what is going on here? Thanks

Comment: Are you reusing the same db backup file name for `product_db` every time you take a backup?

Comment: To @DMason's point, if you're backing up to the same filename every time, you are probably appending your backups to that file.  To check this, use the [`RESTORE HEADERONLY`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178536.aspx) command to inspect what backups have been written to the file.

Comment: To @MikeFal 's point ... what's the backup command you're actually running?

Comment: Hi thanks for the replies. Backup command is in the edit. I'll take alook at RESTORE HEADERONLY

Comment: When I run the restore headeronly command against the backup. 4 results are returned. @DMason Yes, it's using the same backup name everytime. Is there a way to restore the latest backup?

Comment: Here are the steps for restoring from SSMS.  It has details that pertain to your scenario:  http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms177429.aspx

Comment: if you dont care about retaining multiple backups (and if you're on 2008 or greater), you can change your backup command from `BACKUP DATABASE [${secDb}] TO DISK = '${winMssqlPath}\\${secDb}_tmp.bak'` to `BACKUP DATABASE [${secDb}] TO DISK = '${winMssqlPath}\\${secDb}_tmp.bak' WITH COPY_ONLY, INIT`

Comment: Unfortunately it's SQLServer 2005. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Thanks for the help on this, turns out the previous backup was not being deleted. The target that deletes the backup didn't fail out when it could not find the path to the backup. Whitespaces in the path, the parsing of the path was not working properly.